# Any trick to control spacing on table-cell elements?

Tags: html, css, css-tables, cellspacing

I use the display properties `table` and `table-cell` to get equal heights on columns.

One way to control spacing between columns is to define `border-collapse`, but that doesn't allow for control per element-basis, the same spacing between all `table-cell` elements gets applied.

**Is there any sort of trick to achieve the normal margin/padding effect on individual `table-cell` elements?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add `display:block;` to child element of the `table-cell div`...it will work.

Answer (score -1):

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="10">
<tr>
<td>First</td>
<td>Row</td>
</tr>   
<tr>
<td>Second</td>
<td>Row</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is a CSS question.